# I'm trying to use sendgrid to send an attachment using okhttp

Tags: android, email-attachments, okhttp, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm trying to use SendGrid to send emails from my android application.  I can't use Danny Santiago's Sendgrid library due to dependency collisions, so I'm trying to use OKHttp.  The only problem with OKHttp is that is does not allow the sending of input streams, which is what Danny Santiago's library uses to send an attachment.  OKhttp will allow a byte array or a file, but sending a file does not seem to work.  Here's what I have so far.

```
fun sendEmail(email: Email) {
    val formBody = MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)

    if (email.getAttachments().size > 0) {
        val it = email.getAttachments().entries.iterator()
        val  MEDIA_TYPE_JPEG  = MediaType.parse("image/jpeg");
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            val entry = it.next() as Map.Entry<*, *>
            formBody.addFormDataPart("File", String.format(PARAM_FILES, entry.key),
                    RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_JPEG,entry.value as File))
        }
 }

val request Request.Builder()
                .url(url + endpoint)
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + this.password)
                .post(formBody.build() as RequestBody)
                .build()
try {
        val response = this.client.newCall(request).execute()
        Timber.e("Status message", response.body())
        return SendGrid.Response(response.code(), response.message())
} catch (e: IOException) {
        throw SendGridException(e)
}
}
```

Do I have to send a byte array input stream or can I get away with sending a byte array?

Comment: create your own custom `RequestBody` that reads the data from `InputStream` then - implement `writeTo`, `contentType` and `contentLength` - see https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/RequestBody.java#L104 for more info

Comment: actually you can leave `contentLength` with the default implementation if you dont know your stream size

Comment: @pskink - working on that now.